# How to use language C to obtain the intensity of every pixel of an image?

Tags: c, image-processing

AKA how to transform a bmp image into a 2D matrix of its intensity value for every pixel?

Comment: Please try something first. This is a very broad question. Please take some time to read [this site's help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the pages ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Fgg,

One way could be to average the intensities of each pixel (red, green, and blue for example) and average them.

For example:
    Red is 128, Blue is 128, and Green is 128, the intensity would be 128.
    Red is 0, Blue is 100, Green is 255, the intensity would be 118.

If the pixel has an intensity value built into it, you can average those across the entire image. Some images have meta tags which include a brightness, that could be used as well. The averaging above though, is a way I've used in the past inside of a program and it's worked rather well to determine the brightness of the image.

Edit: I need to warn you though, that more complex algorithms may be needed, because the overall average of the RGB values may not work the way you want them to, because of the limits of averaging. For example, really bright pixels may actually increase the brightness of the image, but you may not see it in your result. Similarly, the brightness value obtained through averaging may not accurately represent the true brightness of the image, depending on the pattern of bright pixels.

Question is a bit vague but I hope my answer helps!

Dan Chase

Comment: Wa! so fast. Actually I m little confused by the defination of intensity, it seems that this is not a clear concept. But I think for simple project, just computing it as average of RGB should be OK.

Comment: For more detail, is CImage a good way to deal with this problem ?

Comment: CImage doesn't contain a magical get_intensity function, but you can use GetPixel to get the values for each pixel.. I wouldn't do that, instead I would get the whole image into a memory structure and iterate through it manually. Edit: GetBits may help you from a CImage perspective.

Comment: Thanks again, I know CImage doesn't have function getting intensity directly, I plan to use getPixel. Anyway, thank u very much

Comment: You're very welcome, please don't forget to mark the answer checkmark if you feel I answered the question adequately. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches for deriving intensity from `RGB` coordinates.
One of the most popular ones, used in the `YCbCr` color model is by applying a linear transformation, typically `Y = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B`

Other approaches either average or take the `max(R, G, B)`. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness).

Comment: Most of the better approaches to calculating the 'brightness' of an image take into account how the human eye reacts to the visible spectrum. (the rgb values)